# cannot find symbol method required() javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef

Tags: java, spring, jaxb

I am getting the below error when using the jdk 1.6 but it is working in 1.7

```
cannot find symbol method required() javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementRef
```

any idea?

```
    @XmlElementRef(name = "test", type = JAXBElement.class, required = false)
    protected JAXBElement<String> test;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check documentation of XmlElementRef annotation in Java 1.6 [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementRef.html). There is no `required` element in it. That is why you are getting this exception.

Comment: in the same site can you see in the bottom...
I am able to see the attribute info  "required"

Comment: You have table with Optional Element Summary and there is no required element in int. This attribute was introduced in java7 as Jens mentioned.

Comment: Ohh. cool I didn't noticed properly. i refers javaee 6 doc(http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementRef.html). tnx +1

Comment: If this answer helped you you can mark it as [accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Note the subtle difference between Java **SE** and Java **EE**. Java SE [1.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementRef.html) does not have the `required` element. Java SE 1.7 does have it. Java EE 1.**5** does not have the `required` element, but Java EE 1.6+ does

Answer (score 3):

This attribute is introduced in java7. So it is not available in java6

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementRef.html able to see the required attribute in this doc.

Comment: Ya you are correct. referd wrong doc javaee 6 (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementRef.html) +1